# OpenAPI Swagger not showing examples

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

We are using OpenAPI and openapi-generator-maven-plugin with Spring Boot. We're trying to create an example object in our response. We've followed the suggestions of a number of different web pages, especially this one:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/

But no matter what we try, we either can't get the example data to show up, or it gives us a compile error.

For instance, this seems to be what we should be using, from the doc we've seen:

```
    patch:
      tags:
        - Color
      operationId: testing
      description: test
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Return existing colors in a season
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  testName:
                    type: string
                example:
                  testname: amy
```

But this is causing compile errors in the generated code for the API:

```
ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", "\"{\\"testname\\":\\"amy\\"}\"");
```

There are too many escape characters in the code above, there should not be double escapes.

Here is the plugin config from our POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>FlexPLM-ACL</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/apis/flexplm-acl.yml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <apiPackage>com.dcsg.pdcomm.flexplmacl.api</apiPackage>
                <!-- Both of these APIs use the exact same DTOs, so we have put them into the same package -->
                <modelPackage>com.dcsg.pdcomm.flexplm.dto</modelPackage>
                <modelNameSuffix>DTO</modelNameSuffix>
                <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                <configOptions>
                    <library>spring-boot</library>
                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                    <java8>true</java8>
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                </configOptions>
                <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

We've tried all different combinations of quoting and indentation, but to no avail. Please help us!

Comment: Looks like a bug in the openapi-generator, you should open an issue at https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues. Btw, does it work if you remove the schema-level `example` and add `example: amy` under the `testName` property instead?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it does work with the single example, but we need to create example objects. We were just deconstructing to try to figure out why we weren’t seeing our example data.

Comment: There is a bug, we opened an issue:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3140